# Convert all youtube link to embed

Tags: content, embed, youtube

I have this function to convert any YouTube URL in any post or page to embed :-

```
function embed_youtube_an($post_content) {
  global $posts; 
  //preg_match('|http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|', $posts->post_content, $matches);
  preg_match('#http://w?w?w?.?youtube.com/watch\?v=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)#s', $posts->post_content, $matches);

 if (!empty($matches[1])) { 
    $post_content = '<object width="415" height="250">';
      $post_content .= '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $matches[1] . '&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>';
      $post_content .= '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>';
      $post_content .= '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>';
      $post_content .= '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $matches[1] . '&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="415" height="250"></embed>';
      $post_content .= '</object>';
      $post_content = $post_content;

  }
     return $post_content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'embed_youtube_an');
```

But when open post , all YouTube URL does not show in embed.

Where are the problem?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking (taken the info from your comments on Howdy McGees answer). Please [edit] your question to explain your goal in detail. If English is a problem, take some friend to assist you with rewording it. Thanks.

Comment: Please consult the [help] and read [ask] to see how things work on this site. Editing answers to reply is not how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please take a [tour] and learn how this site (and for that matter all SE sites) works.

Comment: OEmbed should take care of convert YouTube links into videos. What happens when you remove your code? http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

After reviewing your edit, you may want to try following [These Instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)

> To embed a video or another object into a post or page, place its URL into the content area. Make sure the URL is on its own line and not hyperlinked (clickable when viewing the post).

---

It sounds like you would want to use [`wp_get_oembed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get) - The examples look like this:

Retrieve the embed code for a URL from a supported oEmbed provider:

```
<?php $embed_code = wp_oembed_get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkEvSjdDfiA'); ?>
```

Retrieve the embed code for a URL from a supported oEmbed provider - with width argument:

```
<?php $embed_code = wp_oembed_get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkEvSjdDfiA', array('width'=>400)); ?>
```

If that doesn't work you could probably apply ['the_content' filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content):

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkEvSjdDfiA' );
```

But that filter is probably overkill for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How can use `apply_filters( 'the_content', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkEvSjdDfiA' );` ??

Comment: I have more than youtube link in all posts, How can do that

Comment: @user2933912 How are you collecting your links? How are you echoing out your "content"? Please edit your original question and add this code with a little more detail.

Comment: View my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, But i dont knew the url, and i have more than 2000 post have Youtube url, So what the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the URL, put your editor in TEXT mode. Lots of people don't notice the visual editor converts HTML special characters, and deactivates links.

Answer (score 0):

You are making wrong use of the [`the_content` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

Why your code is not working

- You are not returning anything back to the referenced content
- Even if your condition fails, you should pass the referenced content back, otherwise nothing will be displayed if your condition returns `false`
- Your [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function is using the wrong `subject`. Use the referenced content here. (This is just a note, you don't need to call the global `$post`)
- Your `pattern` is also wrong, it does not match any pattern thus failing and returning the content as-is

With the current code that you have, I have gone with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393008/1908141). It has to be noted that from your original question that you are using the following format

- `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=related` and
- `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw`.

This code **only** works on the format `watch?v=`

I have modified your code accordingly:

```
add_filter('the_content', function ($post_content) 
{ 
    parse_str( parse_url( $post_content, PHP_URL_QUERY ),  $matches);

    if (!empty($matches['v'])) { 
        $post_content = '<object width="415" height="250">';
        $post_content .= '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $matches['v'] . '&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param>';
        $post_content .= '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>';
        $post_content .= '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>';
        $post_content .= '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $matches['v'] . '&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="415" height="250"></embed>';
        $post_content .= '</object>';
        $post_content = $post_content;
    }
    return $post_content;
});
```

**EDIT**

As a test, the following code

```
<?php
$string = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4kxS1ksqtw&feature=related';
parse_str( parse_url( $string, PHP_URL_QUERY ),  $matches);
?><pre><?php var_dump($matches); ?></pre><?php
```

gives the following output when dumped

```
array(2) {
  ["v"]=>
  string(11) "C4kxS1ksqtw"
  ["feature"]=>
  string(7) "related"
}
```

Comment: i try your code and not work with me

Comment: Before your conditional statement, do a `var_dump($matches)` and see what is printed and work from there. Also, try removing your condition and check if your code inside your conditional is working as expected

Comment: its something, its still show me youtube link

Comment: See my update. Take note of the exceptions.